# What does "yet tacky jacket to the dry cleaner's" mean?

Tags: meaning

Ramsey and his team are tring to track Jaob using biometrics.
Ramsey speaks to Tej, who believes that a good old-fashioned
tracking chip would've put them within like six feet of Jakob:

> Ramsey: Yeah, uh, strong argument there, Tej, but tracking chips
> follow the chip. Before we know it, we'd be chasing some expensive **yet
> tacky jacket to the dry cleaner's**.

What does "yet tacky jacket to the dry cleaner's" mean? Does it mean tracking
wrong location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"expensive yet tacky" is an adjectival phrase (tacky meaning looking cheap, so it contrasts with "expensive", and that's why "yet" is used instead of "and")

It describes the jacket.  The jacket is expensive. The jacket is tacky.

We are then told that the people would be:

> chasing (the jacket) to the dry cleaners

A "dry cleaner" is a clothes washing place that uses chemicals instead of water.

If you put a tracking chip in the jacket, and the man takes the jacket to be cleaned, you won't know where the man is.